# Django Ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

Django isn't playing well with Ajax. Not entirely sure where the problem is.

This is what I have right now, and according to many sources it is the correct pattern. However, I am still not getting the result I'm expecting.

Views:

```
def index(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        brand_id = request.GET.get('brand', '')
        brand = Brand.objects.get(id=brand_id)

        json_response = {'brand': {'brand_name': brand.brand_name}}

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(json_response),
            content_type='application/json')        

    return render(request, 'showdb/index.html', {'user': ''})
```

Template:

```
var data = "1";    
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "/index/",
        data: data,
        datatype: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("failure");
        }
    })
```

Comment: any error that you are getting?

Comment: No errors apart from the Failure alert. What I would like to get is the alert with the brand name.

Comment: is "Getting there..." getting printed ??

Comment: No, it's not. Which is even more confusing.

Comment: put the print out of the if and try

Comment: No, that didn't work...

Comment: use error function like `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {}` and log the 3 parameters and check

Comment: That doesent return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to send the `csrf_token` this is used for avoid [Cross Site Request Forgery attacks](http://www.veracode.com/security/csrf), [CSRF django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) You have 2 options to solve this problem:

The first one is the less secure and used, the second one dot 1 is which I recomend:

```
1.- Use csrf_exempt in your view:

from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
      #CODE#

2.- Send the csrf_token to django


    2.1 In some place of your html  put {%csrf_token%}
        then in your javascript put

        var data = {'brand': 1, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val()};
        ## ajax request

     2.2 If you are doing the ajax request with the javascript into a script tag, I mean not in a .js file you can do this:


         <script>
        var data = {'brand': 1, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': "{{csrf_token}}"};
          </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I am still getting a failure. I think that the problem lies in my views setup.

Comment: Which way did you use?

Comment: @DGDD The problem lies in my code i did put {%csrf_toke%} and was {%csrf_token%}, see my edit please

Comment: I tried both, but still nothing. I am quite certain that the problem lies in the Views. On my console I am getting the following message: "GET /index/?brand=1&csrfmiddlewaretoken=1b4q2UHu8jtlF8uBna7eeOGPV74jJowL HTTP/1.1" 404 2984

Comment: Yeah the problem lies in your view, you should have to separate views one for the ajax request and another one for the get request.